# How do I interpret a simple linear regression model when both dependent and independent variables are square root transformed?

Tags: r, regression, data-transformation, normality-assumption

## Overview

- I built a simple linear regression model to understand if Universal Healthcare Index predicts suicides.
- My independent variable is Universal Healthcare Index (scale from 1 to 100). The variable name in my data is called "Trans_uhc". In order to meet the normality assumption, I used a sqrt(max(x) - x)) transformation to normalize a negative skew.
- My dependent variable is suicides per 100k population. In order to meet the normality assumption, I used the sqrt(y) transformation to normalize a positive skew.

## Simple Linear Regression Output

[image: Linear Regression Model Output]

## Help Needed

As you can see from the above output, my predictor variable is significant. However, how would I interpret this outcome? For example, if the data was not transformed, I would be able to interpret the linear relationship as "when Universal Healthcare Index increases by 1 point, suicides/100k people decrease by .18879." However, I cannot do that because of the transformation.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What is the max of x? The actual number, I mean.

Comment: @BigBendRegion max(x) = max(Universal Healthcare Index) = 88

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=interpret+regression+root

Comment: The questions suggested do not provide an answer for this case

Comment: @David Agreed. Thanks!

Comment: I disagree.  The duplicate questions address an identical case with only trivial variation in details.  There's no point to having threads on this site for every one of the (infinitely many) conceivable root transformations of variables.